# How to use comboBox variable outside of class or take variable inside of comboBox method

Tags: java, swing, methods, combobox, frame

I am coding in java-eclipse and trying to get values by using comboBoxes but these values are not visible in another functions to use. Whenever I try to move the classes to inside of the class where comboBoxes are declared , the functions variables become invisible. 
Here is the problem step by step ;
1. This is the method where i want to use comboBox values;

```
public void ata(int P1_x, int P1_y, int P2_x, int P2_y, String P1_direction, String P2_direction,int array[][],int array1[][])
{  
        if(P1_direction=="Horizontal")
        {
            gemiatadikey(P1_x,P1_y,array);
        }
        else
        {
            gemiatayatay(P1_x,P1_y,array);
        }
        if(P2_direction == "Horizontal")
        {
            gemiatadikey(P2_x, P2_y,array1);
        }
        else
            gemiatayatay(P2_x, P2_y,array1);
```

At first i was initializing the values by myself and it was working but then i needed to get these values from user by using anything on panel , since i am not experienced about JFrame and Panels then i couldn't find anything except using comboboxes.From the Desing part of WindowBuilder i added combobexes and added some selections in in .Then some codes are added to my project and i tried to get the values by using this code ;

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
            comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}));
            String P1_direction = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

            JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
            comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}));
            String P2_direction = comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            JComboBox comboBox_2 = new JComboBox();
            comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
            String P1_x = comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int P1_coordinate_x = Integer.parseInt(P1_x);

            JComboBox comboBox_3 = new JComboBox();
            comboBox_3.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
            String P1_y = comboBox_3.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int P1_coordinate_y = Integer.parseInt(P1_y);

            JComboBox comboBox_4 = new JComboBox();
            comboBox_4.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
            String P2_x = comboBox_4.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int P2_coordinate_x = Integer.parseInt(P2_x);

            JComboBox comboBox_5 = new JComboBox();
            comboBox_5.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
            String P2_y = comboBox_5.getSelectedItem().toString();
            int P2_coordinate_y = Integer.parseInt(P2_y);

        }
    });
```

And then i tried to call my "ata" method as ;

```
  ata(P1_coordinate_x, P1_coordinate_y, P2_coordinate_x, P2_coordinate_y, P1_direction, P2_direction, gemiOlanArray, gemiOlanArray1);
```

But it doesn't work because this declaration doesn't see(or get) the P1_coordinate_x , ... etc... I am pretty sure that i do something wrong but i am not familiar to these concepts so how can i deal with this ? Thank you

Comment: I think you shouldn't create a new `ComboBoxModel` on every change?

Comment: How can i edit this code , from your point of view it seems i didn't understand this combobox concept . Can you make some suggestions to use it properly ?

Comment: @user2962529: I can make more suggestions if I can understand your problem better. I suggest you put more effort into framing a better question. A little effort can go a long way towards getting a better answer.

Comment: I hope this version is more clear , sorry for the first poor questioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current posted code unfortunately makes little sense:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
  comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}));
  String P1_direction = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

you're making a new JComboBox, not displaying it anywhere, and immediately extracting the selection from it before any user has had a chance to do anything with it, and this will never work.

Suggestions:

- Don't "move your comboboxes" inside of anywhere. Keep them in the GUI where they belong.
- Be sure that your JComboBoxes are declared as instance fields and are not declared inside of a method or constructor where per scoping rules they will be visible only inside of the scope where they were declared.
- If you need outside classes to be able to check the state of the JComboBoxes, then give the classes that hold and display them public methods that return the currently selected item or index of the combo of interest.
- For more specific help, consider telling us more about your problem and showing more relevant code, preferably an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

For example,

> I am ... trying to get values by using comboBoxes but these values are not visible in another functions to use.

Not visible to what? Where? Have you declared the JComboBoxes as class fields (you should) or are they local to some method or constructor?

> Whenever i try to move the classes to inside of the class where comboBoxes are declared , the functions variables become invisible .

---

**Edit**

Regarding your latest posted code, again, this is doomed to fail:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}));
        String P1_direction = comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

        JComboBox comboBox_1 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"Horizontal", "Vertical"}));
        String P2_direction = comboBox_1.getSelectedItem().toString();

        JComboBox comboBox_2 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_2.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
        String P1_x = comboBox_2.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int P1_coordinate_x = Integer.parseInt(P1_x);

        JComboBox comboBox_3 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_3.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
        String P1_y = comboBox_3.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int P1_coordinate_y = Integer.parseInt(P1_y);

        JComboBox comboBox_4 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_4.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
        String P2_x = comboBox_4.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int P2_coordinate_x = Integer.parseInt(P2_x);

        JComboBox comboBox_5 = new JComboBox();
        comboBox_5.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"}));
        String P2_y = comboBox_5.getSelectedItem().toString();
        int P2_coordinate_y = Integer.parseInt(P2_y);

    }
});
```

As explained above, you're creating JComboBoxes that are never displayed on a GUI, and trying to extract information from the before a user has had any chance of interacting with them, even if they were displayed in a GUI. Either one of these mistakes would be enough to make the code fail.

This code also is in error:

```
public void ata(int P1_x, int P1_y, int P2_x, int P2_y, String P1_direction, String P2_direction,int array[][],int array1[][])
{  
        if(P1_direction=="Horizontal")
        {
            gemiatadikey(P1_x,P1_y,array);
        }
```

Because you're using `==` to compare Strings rather than the `equals(...)` method. `==` compares if one object is the same as another object, something that is not what you want to know. You want to know if Strings have the same information, the same characters in the same order, and so you need to use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method.

There's still too much you're not showing us, such as where you declare and display your JComboBoxes. **Again** are you declaring them in the class (yes do this!) or in a method or constructor (no, don't do this!)? Are you trying to access the JComboBoxes from one class or from a separate class? Please consider posting the SSCCE as requested above. Please clarify.

As an aside -- you should avoid using a Window-Builder until you understand the library that you're using since using one shields you from having to learn many of the nuances of the library. Instead for now code your Swing GUI's by hand, refer to the Swing tutorials and the Java API.

Comment: I edited my question , sorry for my poor english , if it isn't clear please let me know and i will try to give more information .Since the whole project contains more than a thousand code i couldn't copy them here.

Comment: @user2962529: see edits to answer above. And no, don't display all the program's code, but hopefully you've got classes of reasonable size that you can show us. Again we prefer an [sscce](http://sscce.org) if you can create and post one.